# How do I import a text file into a python program to maintain a nested list?

Tags: python, user-interface, text

I have a project where we are making a quiz GUI and in the project, we have to have a text file of questions that we need to preload into the GUI to display. For each question, there is the question, 4 answer choices, and feedback, all typed as separate string values. I don't know how to load this into the GUI though to actually keep all the information together. Also, there is the option to add new questions in the gui, so I don't know how to best write those back into the text file.

This is what my question text file looks like right now

```
    questions = (
        ['question','answer', 'answer', 'answer', 'answer', 'feedback',],
        ['question','answer', 'answer', 'answer', 'answer', 'feedback'])
```

This is what I coded that didn't work

```
    with open('questions.txt', 'r') as file:
       questions = list(file)
```

Comment: Consider maintaining a lightweight db like `sqlite` to store questions.

Comment: if you don't want to use `sqlite` as @รยקคгรђשค said, at least you should use `json` or `csv` to store youd questions.

Comment: Okay, I will change it to a json file now. Would I open it in my program and have it load the same way?

Answer (score 0):

Now first of all, we need some info of your **question.txt** file to know how it looks like. I'm going to assume that they are exactly written as you expressed:

```
question, answer, answer, answer, answer, feedback
question, answer, answer, answer, answer, feedback
```

separated by commas for each column, and newline ("\n") for every question.

You would first want to store the contents of your **question.txt** into a variable:

```
with open("questions.txt", "r") as r:
    q = r.readlines()
questions = q.split("\n")  # your line separator
```

Then you traverse thru each question, and group them to a list

```
big_list = []
for question in questions:
    small_list = []
    cols = question.split(",")  # your column separator 
    for col in cols:
        small_list.append(col)
    big_list.append(small_list)
```

Now the **big_list** should be the one you need initially.

Comment: Would I be able to add the small lists into the big list to keep my overall data structure so I can access the questions specifically by doing big_list[i][0]?

Comment: It should work as a 2D array, and thus its elements are accessible using big_list[i][k].